# Uploading to GCS from Twisted

Tags: python, twisted, google-cloud-storage

I need to put files into Google's cloud storage from a twisted application.

I had been using Amazon and `txAWS` but now I'm using GCS I'm not sure if anything exists which will let me do this?

Is it possible to use `txAWS` with GCS? It sounds like an odd question but it's possible to use `boto`'s `S3Connection` with GCS so maybe there's a way to do the same with `txAWS`?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [Twisted Web client](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html) with the [GCS JSON API](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/). Here's an example of listing the contents of a bucket:

```
import json
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.error import Error
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers

GCS_BASE_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta1'
GCS_API_KEY = '<your-api-key>'
GCS_BUCKET = '<your-bucket>'

class ResponseAccumulate(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, finished):
        self.finished = finished
        self.fullbuffer = ''

    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        print 'Received %d bytes.' % len(bytes)
        self.fullbuffer += bytes

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if isinstance(reason, Error):
            print 'Finished receiving body:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        else:
            parsed = json.loads(self.fullbuffer)
            print 'Bucket contents:'
            for item in parsed['items']:
              print ' ', item['id']
        self.finished.callback(None)

agent = Agent(reactor)

d = agent.request(
    'GET',
    '%s/b/%s/o?key=%s' % (GCS_BASE_URL, GCS_BUCKET, GCS_API_KEY),
    Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted Web Client Example']}),
    None)

def cbResponse(response):
    print 'Response received', response.code
    finished = Deferred()
    response.deliverBody(ResponseAccumulate(finished))
    return finished
d.addCallback(cbResponse)

def cbShutdown(ignored):
    reactor.stop()
d.addBoth(cbShutdown)

reactor.run()
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I use this with a secret key- presumably I need to sign the urls?